# How to add custom mask in Angular using ngx-mask?

Tags: angular, input, mask, mat-input, ngx-mask

I am trying to add a custom mask in angular using regular expression.

Here is the mask I want:

1. Characters allowed: Capital Letters, Small Letters, and Numbers
2. Length of the field: 20
3. Can start the input using an alphabet and number as well.

---

**WHAT I TRIED!**

```
public customPatterns = { 'X': { pattern: new RegExp('\[a-zA-Z0-9\]')} };
```

```
<input formControlName ="number" matInput placeholder="Number" mask="X{20}">
```

---

PROBLEM I AM FACING!

Using the above expression, I am able to write only numbers.
I am not able to right any alphabet character neither at the start nor in the middle.